# Jquery code works only on refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

Everything works as expected, but I have a small problem. The code works perfectly but only if I refresh the page. It should work immediately after the user log in. Is the a way to make it work instantly after log in?

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname == "/mesaje") {
    $('.new_messages_count').hide();
  }
  
  $('body').append('<span class="invisible-total-messages" style= "display: hidden;">*</span>');
  
  $('.invisible-total-messages').load('/mesaje .msglist .errorbg', null, function() {
    var sum = 0;
    
    $('.invisible-total-messages .errorbg').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    
    if (sum !== 0) {
      $('#menu .new_messages_count').html(sum);
      $('#admin-menu .new_messages_count').html(sum);
      $('.mobile .new_messages_count').html(sum);
    }
  }).hide();
});
```

Comment: The code will execute as soon as the page loads. Which specific part of this is 'not working'? Also, is your site using AJAX to load the page content when the user logs in - ie. an SPA architecture?

Comment: After I press the login button, the jquery doesn't run, only if I hit ctrl+f5 to reload the page for exemple. It should run instantly. And yes, I use AJAX.

Comment: You'll need to provide us with more *context*.  "*After I press the login button*" - there's no login button in the code provided nor code to handle it.  What does clicking the button do?  Redirect to a new page?  An Ajax request?  Your code is assigned to doc.ready rather than a login button.